# Deleting wchar_t pointer crashes on 64-bit build

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management

I've got a managed c++ library that is crashing when a delete statement is encountered, but it only crashes on a 64-bit build.  The code is:

```
LPWSTR pwmsURL = NULL;
pPresentationCtx->GetStringValue(L"WMS_PRESENT_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_NAME", 17, &pwmsURL, 0);
String^ wmsURL = gcnew String(pwmsURL);
//this delete is the problem line...
delete [] pwmsURL;
```

If I comment out the delete, everything works fine, but I don't want to create a memory leak.  No problems on a 32-bit build.  Any idea what's going on with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete[]` can only delete memory allocated by `new[]`. To use it here, you'd need to know exactly how `pPresentationCtx->GetStringValue` allocated the returned memory, and it's seemingly *not* via `new[]` - hence the crash.

I would imagine that the API you're using provides a function specifically for deallocating memory created by its provided functions. Check the documentation (could be something like `GlobalFree` if this is Win32).

Comment: Thanks - went back and dug into the docs, it was indeed using CoTaskMemAlloc/CoTaskMemFree .